# Валидация нескольких групп checkbox'ов через jquery validation по name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Есть такой html:

```
<input name="professional_options[Classroom]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="professional_options[Classroom]">
<input name="professional_options[Interviewing]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="professional_options[Interviewing]">
<input name="professional_options[Social Events]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="professional_options[Social Events]">

<input name="should_color[White]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="should_color[White]">
<input name="should_color[Beige]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="should_color[Beige]>
<input name="should_color[Blue]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="should_color[Blue]">
```

Как я могу задать правило чтобы в группе **professional_options** и **should_color** были отмечены хотябы по одному checkbox'у, в проекте используется jquery validation

Comment: В модели, я полагаю, уже валидацию сделали? Вас интересует только сторона jQuery-validation?

Comment: @D-side да, на странице слишком много групп, хотелось бы сделать этот как-то по хитрому